# How to randomly remove part of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

If I have a dictionary with keys a0,a1,a2,b1,b2,b3 and I only want to randomly pop two items with keys starting with 'a' and not 'b', how to modify the below code?

```
for key in random.sample(d.keys(), n): 
    del d[key] # or d.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for key in random.sample([k for k in d if k.startswith("a")], n): 
    del d[key]
```

`[k for k in d if k.startswith("a")]` gets all the keys that start  with `a`, so `random.sample` will return `n` keys that start with `a`

```
In [21]: import random  
In [22]: d = {"a1":1,"a2":2,"b1":1,"b2":2}    
In [23]: for key in random.sample([k for k in d if k.startswith("a")], 2):
   ....:         del d[key]
   ....:         
In [24]: d
Out[24]: {'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a solution that is easier to grasp:
You can take advantage of the fact that dictionaries are exxentially created in "random order" and the fact that the iteration order will change each time the dict is mutated.

```
count=0
for key in d:
    if key[0]=='a':
        if count<2:
            del d[key]
            count+=1
        else:
            break
```

Comment: it is not a random order, while how the keys and values are added is usually not going to match the output you will get the same key/value pairing order every time you iterate over the dict once the dict is not changed.

Comment: What about when you change the dict? e.g. pop 2 elements? I was under the impression this would cause a new ordering, thus being random from the users perspective